# How does hosting work while making an R app with Shiny

Tags: r, security, shiny, shinyapps

I am a bit new to Shiny and am working on creating a dashboard for my employer. The data that would be displayed is a bit sensitive in nature.

So, eventually, the dashboard will be hosted on my employers site, but I actually have to create a working version of the dash for approval before IT will start working with me on that.

I have been using dummy data until now, but I would like to use some actual data to show key personnel what the dash will look like.

So, my question is, when I run the code I see a copy of the dashboard, but where is this hosted (or is it even hosted at all)? Can anyone find the data (not sure how they would the web address seems non-specific, like http://x.x.x.x or something like that) or is it not really hosted?

I just don’t understand how the backend of this process works.

Comment: If you run the code on your computer, it is on [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost), which is your computer hosting something for itself. Only accessible to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

If it's running off your local machine that's the IP of your machine. Your organization should be firewalled from the rest of the world so that IP Address should only be visible within your organization.

As for discoverability, a lot of organizations will allow you to register a hostname with a given ip address that resolves internally. However, for initial prototyping I've always been okay with just passing around an IP address